# Configure HBase with Ejabberd

Tags: hbase, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks

I am planning to use HBase for my Ejabberd Server. I was trying to get some documentation on how to configure it but I couldn't so please anyone can help me by giving some documentation link.

Thanks,
Shiva Prasad G

Answer (score 0):

There is no HBase module for ejabberd available at the moment.